# Subclassing UIRefreshControl

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, pull-to-refresh, uirefreshcontrol

I've have to develop a custom `UIRefreshControl` with custom animation (I use an array of png handled by a `UIImageView`). I don't understand if I can subclass `UIRefreshControl` to add my animation like a `subview`:

```
   self.addSubview(MyRefreshControlView)
```

and to develop my own beginRefreshing and and Refreshing methods. Can you help me?

Comment: https://www.appcoda.com/custom-pull-to-refresh/ check this link. You can customize it your way.

Comment: Thank you but I have need of a subclass. Can I subclass UIRefreshControl?

Comment: definitely you can like every other third party control do. You better look for some third party control on www.cocoacontrols.com as well.